# Resumable uploads (Google Drive SDK for Android or Java)

Tags: android, file-upload, google-drive-api

I had referred to [Check progress for Upload & Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580109/check-progress-for-upload-download-google-drive-api-for-android-or-java),  [Resumable upload using Drive API for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326523/resumable-upload-using-drive-api-for-android) and [Direct and Resumable Media Uploads](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload).

However, I cannot get solution from them, and the resumable media upload is always failed.

My test step is try to disconnect WiFi/connect to another WiFi during upload, and then upload the same file again, but it always upload the file from beginning.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Logcat:

```
08-13 21:56:02.541 13190 13968 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 19%
08-13 21:56:02.931 13190 13968 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 19%
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x7ac0ba00: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:692)
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:316)
08-13 21:56:03.262 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:417)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.example.drivequickstart.UploadFileActivity$UploadFileTask.doInBackground(UploadFileActivity.java:94)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at com.example.drivequickstart.ServiceBaseActivity$GeneralDriveTask.doInBackground(ServiceBaseActivity.java:1)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-13 21:56:03.272 13190 13968 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-13 21:56:12.792 13190 13190 D UploadFileActivity:  onConnected()
08-13 21:56:12.812 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [INITIATION_STARTED]
08-13 21:56:13.432 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [INITIATION_COMPLETE]
08-13 21:56:13.953 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 0%
08-13 21:56:14.203 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 0%
08-13 21:56:14.514 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 0%
08-13 21:56:14.754 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 0%
08-13 21:56:15.044 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 1%
08-13 21:56:15.294 13190 14305 D UploadFileActivity: [MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: 1%
```

Code snip:

```
private class UploadFileTask extends GeneralDriveTask {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());

            // File's metadata.
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
            //body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
            fileMetadata.setMimeType("video/mp4");
            fileMetadata.setFileSize(fileContent.length());

            // File's binary content

            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("video/mp4", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileContent)));
            mediaContent.setLength(fileContent.length());

            Drive.Files.Insert insert = getDriveService().files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent).set("uploadType", "resumable");
            insert.set("uploadType", "resumable");
            insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
            insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
            insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(mUploadFileProgressListener);

            File file = insert.execute();   
            if (file != null)
                showToast("Video uploaded: " + file.getTitle());                
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            GetGoogleDriveToken();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }   
}

private static class UploadFileProgressListener implements MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener {
    @Override
    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
        switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
            case INITIATION_STARTED:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[INITIATION_STARTED]");
              break;
            case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[INITIATION_COMPLETE]");
              break;

            case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                int percent = (int)(uploader.getProgress() * 100);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS] progress: " + percent + "%");
                break;
            case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[MEDIA_COMPLETE] progress: 100%");
                break;
            default:
                break;              
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that MediaHttpUploader did not handle resume upload well.
The reason is that "Request the upload status." mentioned in 
[Google Drive SDK Upload Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable)  always fail to get Content-Range.

So, The way to solve it is polling Content-Range all the time during upload.
Thus it's able to resuming an interrupted upload by "Resume the upload from the point where it left off."

```
private String getUploadID(Uri fileUri, String token) {         
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] +++");

    String upload_id = "";

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
    String fileName = fileContent.getName();
    String contentLength = String.valueOf(fileContent.length());
    String mimeType = getMimeFromURI(fileUri);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] fileName : " + fileName);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] contentLength : " + contentLength);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] mimeType : " + mimeType);

    try {
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type", mimeType);
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length", contentLength);       

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("title", fileName);
        byte[] postData = jobj.toString().getBytes();           

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        if (location.contains("upload_id")) {
            String[] uploadParameters = location.split("upload_id");
            upload_id = uploadParameters[1].replace("=", "");
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] Response Code : " + responseCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] Response Location : " + location);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] Response uploadID : " + upload_id);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }               

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[sendResumableHttpRequest] ---");

    return upload_id;
}

private void putFileWithUploadID(Uri fileUri, String token, long range) {       
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] +++");

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
    String fileName = fileContent.getName();
    String contentLength = String.valueOf(fileContent.length());
    String mimeType = getMimeFromURI(fileUri);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] fileName : " + fileName);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] contentLength : " + contentLength);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] mimeType : " + mimeType);

    long totalBytesFromDataInputStream = 0;

    try {
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" + mUploadID;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mimeType);
        //con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);

        long nextByte = 0;
        if (range == 0) {               
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", contentLength);
        }
        else {
            nextByte = range + 1;
            long remainContentLength = Long.parseLong(contentLength) - nextByte;
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(remainContentLength));
            String contentRange = "bytes " + (range + 1) + "-" + ( Long.parseLong(contentLength) - 1) + "/" + contentLength;
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", contentRange);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] Content-Length : " + String.valueOf(remainContentLength));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] Content-Range : " + contentRange);
        }
        con.setDoOutput(true);          

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileContent)); 

        int bytes = 0;              
        byte[] bufferOut = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytes = inputStream.read(bufferOut)) != -1) {               
            if (nextByte > 0) {
                nextByte = nextByte - bytes;
                if (nextByte >= 0) continue;
            }
            wr.write(bufferOut, 0, bytes);  
            totalBytesFromDataInputStream += bytes;
        }                                  
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] totalBytesFromDataInputStream:" + totalBytesFromDataInputStream);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        isUploadCompleted = true;
        isInterrupted = false;
        mLastUploadBytes = 0;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] isUploadCompleted:" + isUploadCompleted);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] isInterrupted:" + isInterrupted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
        isInterrupted = true;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] isInterrupted:" + isInterrupted);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] totalBytesFromDataInputStream:" + totalBytesFromDataInputStream);
    } finally {
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[putFileWithUploadID] ---");
}

private void putFileWithUploadID(Uri fileUri, String token) {   
    putFileWithUploadID(fileUri, token, 0);
}   

private long requestUploadStatus(Uri fileUri, String token) {           
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] +++");

    String range_so_far = "0";

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
    String contentLength = String.valueOf(fileContent.length());

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] contentLength : " + contentLength);

    try {
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" + mUploadID;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", "bytes */*");           

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        String rangeHeader = con.getHeaderField("Range");
        if (rangeHeader != null && rangeHeader.length() > 0) {
            String[] range = rangeHeader.split("-");
            range_so_far = range[1];
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] Response Code : " + responseCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] Response rangeHeader : " + rangeHeader);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] Response range_so_far : " + range_so_far);                        

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }               

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[requestUploadStatus] ---");

    return Long.parseLong(range_so_far);
}
```

Comment: from this answer it seems that resumableUpload is not really supported in the Drive SDK (as it looks like you're not able to use any of their libs). Is there a way to do this within the Drive SDK for java?

Comment: as my understanding, Google Drive Android API support resumable upload

Comment: @Ali you may get your answer here at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887303/resumable-upload-in-drive-rest-api-v3