# Update a file using Google drive rest api v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I am following https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051252 method to upload new files which is working fine. So i thought doing some minor changes will work for updating existing file. I can generate session uri using PATCH instead of POST. But when doing uploading part i am getting 403 forbidden response. I can successfully do update file using v2 api. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code for your upload requests to the REST API? Could you also post the response you're getting as there are a few reasons you could be getting 403 https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded

Comment: Please post your code and the full error message

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have added parents in request body which was causing 403 error.